# strcmp not working in while loop

Tags: c, while-loop, strcmp

What I want to do in my C code is to check for user input and validate that they can only type in either "one" or "two". I made a while loop that checks the user input value with `strcmp`, but it does not work. The while loop seem to be ignoring the `getchar();` and going on an infinite loop.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

     int main ()
       {
        char choice[80];
        while(strcmp (choice,"one") != 0 || strcmp (choice,"two") != 0){
        scanf("%s", &choice);
        getchar();
        }
        // if the user enters either one or two, continue executing code...
       return 0;
     }
```

Comment: D'oh! `scanf("%s", choice);`

Comment: picky comment. it is possible that your stack could have 'o', 'n', 'e', 0 at startup, which'd result in no user input. You should initialise choice before using it. or use `do {} while`

Comment: @Armin what do you mean?

Comment: @TomTanner I tried the do/while loop with no luck.

Comment: @user1431627 thats because your condition is wrong. but your code still has undefined behaviour as you are accessing uninitialised memory. strcmp could crash

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I saw 3 issues in your code:

#### 1

```
while(strcmp (choice,"one") != 0 || strcmp (choice,"two") != 0)
```

This condition never evaluates to `false`. Because either the user enters one or two or aything else the any of the or both strcmp condition returns true.

#### 2

```
 scanf("%s", &choice);
```

No need of `&` there. For reading string to an character array using `%s` you don't need to use `&` (because when you specify the name of character array the address is pointed).

Just write like:

```
scanf("%s", choice);
```

#### 3

It's a logical one. You just declared an character array. And on the next line you are using it in `strcmp`. surely the array will have garbage values.

#### My solution:

Implement your code like:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int main ()
{
   char choice[80];
   while(1)
   {
        scanf("%s", choice);
        if(strcmp (choice,"one") == 0 || strcmp (choice,"two") == 0)
        {
           break;
        }
        getchar();
   }
   // if the user enters either one or two, continue executing code...
   return 0;
}
```

Comment: @user1431627: with pleasure :) All the best :)

Comment: But should I declare it as a string instead?

Comment: Declaring it as char choice[];

Comment: @user1431627: No, no need of that. There is no datatype called `string` in C. Either you can use `char arr[50];` or `char *pt;` for storing strings. First one can hold maximum of80 character, but the other one can hold according to the allocated size (it's dynamic)

Comment: Since it's dynamic, should I use it then because I might not be sure how many chars the user will type in? (Sorry if it sounds dumb, im still learning C)

Comment: @user1431627: dynamic in the sense you can control it via run time. For storing string on *ptr you need to allocate memory using malloc like: `char *ptr = (char *)malloc(SIZE);` here SIZE is a variable if value of SIZE is 80, you can store 0 character if it is 120, you can store 120 characters. So in your current context. No change is required. For now just forgot about it. Take a look on this when you get hold on the pointer, malloc and free concepts

Answer (score 11):

Surely you want

```
while(strcmp (choice,"one") != 0 && strcmp (choice,"two") != 0)
```

Your current version will continue to loop if your input doesn't satisfy the *not equal to one* OR the *not equal to two* condition. If it equals *one*, it won't equal *two* etc....

Rarely do you want *not equals* clauses ORed together...

Comment: Especially when the meaning of the whole while clause will *always* be true (at most one of "choice is one" or "choice is two" will be true, and since `strcmp` uses 0 to indicate equality...).

Answer (score 2):

Use AND (&&) operator instead of OR (||).

If you use OR, the statement is true if either condition is true, If you use AND, it's true only if both conditions are true. If AND is used, the loop is executed as long as choice is neither "one" nor "two".

On another note, the keyboard input reading line should be `sscanf("%s",choice);` without the ampersand.

Answer (score 0):

In logical formulas, negation distributes according to [DeMorgan's Laws](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/De_Morgan%27s_laws). So `!(a || b) == (!a && !b)`.